# Configure Domain on VPS Running Cpanel to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain, configuration, vps

I have a VPS, that is running cpanel, which I want to configure to point to an ec2 instance.

I'm slightly confused which settings on **Advanced DNS Zone Editor** under cpanel I need to change to properly point the domain to my ec2 instance.

I've since modified the :

```
mysite.com. 5   IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

to

```
mysite.com. 5   IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (*ec2 instance - elastic ip*)
```

What else is there ?

should I also point:

```
ftp.mysite.com
```

to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (*ec2 instance - elastic ip*)`

If someone can please clarify.

Thank you.

Comment: Admin panels are [off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (see [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258) for some reasons). The community has decided that we want to close both old and new questions when such an admin panel is relevant ([link 1](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8086), [link 2](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you have to update DNS with Elastic IP or Public IP associated with your Ec2 Instance.

You cannot point 2 A records for a single IP though you can have Canonical Name Cname for the domain.

Comment: for `Ftp` though, I have: `ftp.mysite.com. 14400 IN A <amazon elastic ip>` and `mysite.com. 5 IN A <amazon elastic ip>`   is  this wrong? Do I need a new elastic IP for ftp?

Comment: Do the nameservers need to change too?